# Clip beginning and end of lines in R

Tags: r, clip, line

I have a series of lines which I need to 'top and tail' to remove the first and last x meters as roughly illustrated below with buffers of 200 m.

```
library(geojsonio)
library(rgeos)
gurl <- "https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/raw/master/data/leeds-cents.geojson"
cents <- topojson_read(gurl)
gurl <- "https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/raw/master/data/line1.geojson"
l1 <- topojson_read(gurl)
l2 <- gDifference(l1, cents)
plot(l2)
```

[image: single-line]

Problem: It should only remove the beginning and end of the line and not chop it in two.

**Edit: this is a more complex reproducible example**

[image: top and tail]

Reproducible example illustrating how to clip the lines:

```
library(geojsonio)
library(rgeos)
gurl <- "https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/raw/master/data/leeds-cents.geojson"
cents <- topojson_read(gurl)
gurl <- "https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/raw/master/data/leeds-lines.geojson"
routes <- topojson_read(gurl)

out <- gDifference(routes, cents)
plot(routes)
plot(out, col = "grey", add = T)
```

the problem with this is that it cuts some lines in half. So the question is how can I clip only at the beggining and the end of lines without chopping lines in two?

Comment: Its a bit unclear (both the diagram and your explanation!). Is it because the circular buffers are clipping other lines that overlap the buffer? I'm not sure a buffer/difference solution will work in any case since a line might kink back into the buffer zone at any point. Is that the problem? Could you illustrate it with one line?

Comment: If you really want the distance *along the line* then `spsample` can generate points on lines, then you buffer the points with a tiny distance and intersect to split the lines. Loop over each route... Do each end... If the routes don't intersect you should be okay...

Comment: It should only remove stuff at the beginning or end. I know the kinking problem doesn't exist in my data but if it did I'd want it only to remove the first part in the buffer. Simpler example should help. A for loop solution could work (suggestions appreciated) - just wondering if there's another way.

Comment: The buffers are always the first and last points of the line features yeah?

Comment: Yes indeed @Spacedman

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: this is [now](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/commit/6a60453a4560b589fff558293c55a693adcc3a14) a function - toptail() - in stplanr**

This may not be the most elegant or efficient solution, but it seems to work:

```
lcoords <- coordinates(l1)[[1]][[1]]
lpoints <- SpatialPoints(matrix(lcoords[c(1, nrow(lcoords)),], nrow = 2))
proj4string(lpoints) <- proj4string(cents)
sel <- cents[lpoints,]
l2 <- gDifference(l1, sel)
plot(l1, col = "red")
plot(l2, add = T)
```

And here's an implementation for the more complex example:

```
for(i in 1:length(routes)){
  l1 <- routes[i,]
  lcoords <- coordinates(l1)[[1]][[1]]
  lpoints <- SpatialPoints(matrix(lcoords[c(1, nrow(lcoords)),], nrow = 2))
  proj4string(lpoints) <- proj4string(cents)
  sel <- cents[lpoints,]
  l2 <- gDifference(l1, sel)
  if(i == 1){
    routes2 <- l2
  } else {
    routes2 <- tmap::sbind(routes2, l2)
  }
}

plot(cents)
plot(routes, col = "red", add = T)
plot(routes2, add = T)
```

[image: solution]

I'd like to turn this into a function for [stplanr](https://github.com/ropensci/stplanr).

I'll let this linger for a while first though to see if there's a more elegant solution - hope so!